# Two conditions using OR function with FALSE statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Hey I am trying to use conditional formatting to have a row turn red if one column is No or another column has the words False.

I tried two formulas.

One is

```
=OR($W4="No",$X4=FALSE)
```

This works in most cases but it turns the cell red when column X is blank and W = Yes.

The other formula I tried is

```
=OR($W4="No",$X4="FALSE")
```

but this one is turning rows red only if there is a No is column W.  Is there a different way I should write this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends if your "FALSE" is typed plain text or checkbox/boolean...

try:

```
=($W4="no")+($X4=FALSE)+($X4="FALSE")
```

or:

```
=($X4<>"")*(($W4="no")+($X4=FALSE)+($X4="FALSE"))
```